# Using variable in Intern functional test

Tags: intern, leadfoot

I need to use a variable whose value is determined based on the css style pixel. 
The test find the value of left pixel and then select a particular cell. But when i run this test the value is always 0 instead of what it actually should be.

```
 'Test' : function() { 
            var left = 0;
            var remote = this.remote;
            return remote
            .setFindTimeout(5000)

            .findByXpath("//div[@class = 'grid']//div[@class = 'gridCell' and position() = 1]/div[3]")
              .getAttribute("style") 
              .then( function(width) {
                  left = parseInt(width.substring(width.indexOf("left")+6,width.indexOf("width")-4));
              }).end() 
            .f_selectCell("", 0, left)               
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the calls in a Command chain will be executed sequentially, the chain expression itself is parsed and arguments are resolved before execution begins. So in the case of

```
return remote
    .findByXpath('...')
    .getAttribute('style')
    .then(function (width) {
        left = parseInt(width);
    })
    .f_selectCell('', 0, left);
```

the `left` argument to `f_selectCell` is evaluated before the chain ever starts executing. When `left` is reassigned in the `then` callback, `f_selectCell` isn't going to know about it because it has already evaluated `left` to be 0.

Instead, you'll need to call the `f_selectCell` method in a `then` callback, or pass it an `object` that properties can be assigned to.

```
return remote
    // ...
    .then(function (width) {
        left = parseInt(width);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // I'm not entirely sure where f_selectCell is coming from...
        return f_selectCell('', 0, left);
    });
```

or

```
// Put all args to selectCell in this
var selectData = {};

return remote
    // ...
    .then(function (width) {
        selectData.left = parseInt(width);
    })
    // selectCell now takes an object with all args
    // The object is never reassigned during execution. 
    .f_selectCell(selectData);
```